# Custom dimension not working

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics

I've created 2 dimesions in my Analytics. When my user log in my app, I send the dimensions to Google Analytics. I know that have a delay to the dimension appear in report. But it's not appearing.

There's my code:

```
- (void) signInGoogleAnalytics {
    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

    // You only need to set User ID on a tracker once. By setting it on the tracker, the ID will be
    // sent with all subsequent hits.
    [tracker set:kGAIUserId value:self.txtStoreCode.text];

    NSString *dimensionUsuarioLogado = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _txtEmployee.text];
    NSString *dimensionLoja = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _txtStoreCode.text];

    [tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] set:dimensionUsuarioLogado forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]] build]];
    [tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] set:dimensionLoja forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:2]] build]];
}
```

See screenshots
https://postimg.org/image/mz3lmcj3t/

https://postimg.org/image/842ts7qqb/

Its possible to look the parameters cd1 and cd2...(custom dimension) but it's not appear in G.A Report.

Comment: You need to allow up to 24 hours for the data to be processed. The data looks to be there in the hit. Also make sure you don't have any filters that could possibly filter out your data.

Comment: And should scope be session or user?

Comment: What are the dimensions?

Comment: @nyuen https://postimg.org/image/y1tkw32wd/

Comment: That doesn't help too much. You're trying to troubleshoot why the CDs aren't showing up, right? It doesn't matter what scoping is. The data either shows up or not. If the data still doesn't show up after 24 hours, then you'll have to analyse the hit data with a proxy, like Fiddler or Charles.

Comment: @nyuen good idea. I have charles. I will debug it